# AppaholicsUpdateChecker: No Connection Issue

Tags: android, updates

I m new in the "Android Coding" Scene, i have programmed my first application, now i want to implement a auto-update function.

Now i have found this library:
https://github.com/RaghavSood/AppaholicsUpdateChecker

Now i have this onCreate function:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

UpdateChecker checker = new UpdateChecker(this, true);
checker.checkForUpdateByVersionCode("http://app.XXX.in/version.txt");
checker.isUpdateAvailable();
checker.downloadAndInstall("http://app.XXX.in/apk/tGlApp.apk");
    }
```

If i Start now my application an ToastText appears that i have no Internet Connection, Updated failed, but i have a Internet Connection. Internet Access are also allowed in the Manifest File.

The Code above is wrong?

Here my Manifest File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.tglapp"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <supports-screens
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="false"
        android:smallScreens="false"
        android:xlargeScreens="true" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.tglapp.MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN2" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.tglapp.MainActivity2"
            android:configChanges="orientation"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main_activity2"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.tglapp.MainActivity3"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main_activity3" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

With this Update Script i need to allow other things which "android.permission.INTERNET" ?

Comment: Just curious, are you running this from the emulator or from a device? I've had many issues with getting emulators to work with domain names  (I still can't on Mac OS!) Try going to the browser and see if you have access to any site. Also, try an IP address.

Comment: Hi, no i try on the android device only, no emulator, i think that something are wrong with my code , or not?

Comment: Post your manifest file... that might help

Comment: I have edited my first post, the Manifest look like that. But i think that the code in my Activiy onCreate are wrong too , or not? Thx

Comment: Hmm. That looks right. I am not an Android expert myself, or familiar with that library, but you could try a simple `URLConnection` and see if you can get *anywhere*: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLConnection.html

Comment: Hi, i have a webview also included and there it works, it seems that something is wrong in the activity or Manifest. Maybe someone know that library and can help. Thanks a lot abellina.

Comment: This seems to be a bug on my end. I'll take a look when I get home later today.

Comment: Raghav Sood, you have looked after the Bug ? Thx in Advance for a answer.